# Marketing Cloud PHP Integration: Malformed SOAP Request?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I am in the process of using the Marketing Cloud API in a proprietary application.  I have hit a few snags that have prevented me from accessing the data I need.  Because of our tech stack, we are NOT using the SDK but instead a homegrown library.  At the moment, I can access contacts using the Retrieve method however, I cannot page through them or can filter them.  Looking for any assistance.  It is important to note that the API uses SOAP to make the requests.  Here's are the two methods that I am using to access the API.

```php
    /**
     * Queries MC Subscriber Data
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function getMCData() {
        $filterArray = [
            'Property'       => 'SubscriberKey',
            'SimpleOperator' => 'notContains',
            'Value'          => '@'
        ];
        $f           = new SoapVar( $filterArray, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'SimpleFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" );
        $request     = [
            'RetrieveRequest' => [
                'ObjectType'       => 'Subscriber',
                'Properties'       => [ "ID", "EmailAddress", "SubscriberKey", "Status" ],
                'QueryAllAccounts' => false,
                'SimpleFilterPart' => $filterArray,
                'Options'          => [
                    'BatchSize' => 2500, // Adjust batch size as needed
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $response = $this->MCSOAPRequest( 'Retrieve', $request );

        if ( $response->Results ) {
            $data = [];
            echo '<pre>';
            foreach ( $response->Results as $row ) {
                $data[] = [
                    $row->ID,
                    $row->EmailAddress,
                    $row->SubscriberKey,
                    $row->Status
                ];

                print_r( $row );
            }
            echo '</pre>';

            // Build the CSV file
            //          $file_name = storage_path( 'app/mc_status_data_' . time() . '.csv' );
            //          $fp        = fopen( $file_name, 'w' );
            //
            //          foreach ( $data as $fields ) {
            //              fputcsv( $fp, $fields );
            //          }
            //
            //          fclose( $fp );
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array   $request
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function MCSOAPRequest( string $method, array $request = [] ) {
        if ( ! $this->accessToken ) {
            $this->authenticate();
        }

        try {
            // Initialize the SOAP client
            $client = new SoapClient( $this->wsdl, [
                'trace'      => 1,
                'exceptions' => true
            ] );

            $headerVar = new SoapVar( '<fueloauth>' . $this->accessToken . '</fueloauth>', XSD_ANYXML );
            $header    = new SoapHeader( 'http://tempuri.org/', 'RequestParams', $headerVar );
            $client->__setSoapHeaders( [ $header ] );

            // Make the API request
            $response = $client->$method( $request );

            if ( $response->Results ) {
                return $response;
            }

            else {
                return;
            }
        } catch ( SoapFault $e ) {
            // Handle SOAP faults
            //          echo 'SOAP Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            echo $client->__getLastRequest();
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            // Handle other exceptions, e.g., connection errors
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

This call does not go past 2500 records, will NOT paginate and will not filter.  I am assuming that there is something wrong with how I am forming the request.  It took quite a while to figure out the correct way to WRAP the request in SOAP variables.

What am I missing here?  Also, here's a sample SOAP envelope, if that's helpful.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><fueloauth>eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iOiIydG1uMldPMGNPYmZ4UU10YXl4cW96c3giLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJ1cjIwem96cmFjMzQwYXV4cWM3bXkza3QiLCJlaWQiOjUzNDAwMzk3Mywic3RhY2tfa2V5IjoiUzEyIiwicGxhdGZvcm1fdmVyc2lvbiI6MiwiY2xpZW50X3R5cGUiOiJTZXJ2ZXJUb1NlcnZlciIsInBpZCI6NzMxfQ.WwShSAXzFEWTw9-eHVBOa-TgxHCycFpZWsIuTjQaCeE.qHDJ6g3DXo4bHgg7KUuSN9aRcm-Wncr5WFPsBGQJYapeswcnCaiZmw7aekJ4Mi47cmKffgE6XAum0JK51lkpEb1e3HVDay0u-NdhvCOHgSUksZICauKoI1f8gDkV38W0sWiFGlW59wc1cYYq2aDnHk9slCTGJ6fatbkeR</fueloauth></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:RetrieveRequestMsg><ns1:RetrieveRequest><ns1:ObjectType>Subscriber</ns1:ObjectType><ns1:Properties>ID</ns1:Properties><ns1:Properties>EmailAddress</ns1:Properties><ns1:Properties>SubscriberKey</ns1:Properties><ns1:Properties>Status</ns1:Properties><ns1:QueryAllAccounts>false</ns1:QueryAllAccounts><ns1:Options><ns1:BatchSize>2500</ns1:BatchSize></ns1:Options></ns1:RetrieveRequest></ns1:RetrieveRequestMsg></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```